# JList not displaying any objects?

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to figure out how to use JList and I cant seem to get it to display an object into my GUI.

there's a class called Drawing that I'm trying to add to the JList and it just doesnt seem to show..
Any help would be greatly appreciated

here's my code:

```
public class DrawingDisplayer extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {
JLabel title;
JButton draw,pause,clear,
        open,close,
        lines,background;
JSlider speedSlider;
JProgressBar progress;
Drawing drawing;
JFileChooser chooser;
JList fileList;
DefaultListModel listModel; 
JPanel drawPanel;
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public DrawingDisplayer(){

    title = new JLabel("The Drawing Displayer");
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 24));

    draw = new JButton("Draw");
    pause = new JButton("Pause");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    speedSlider = new JSlider();
    progress = new JProgressBar();

    open = new JButton("Open Drawing");
    close = new JButton("Close Drawing");       

    listModel = new DefaultListModel();     
    fileList = new JList(listModel);
    fileList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    fileList.addListSelectionListener(this);
    fileList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileList);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,250));

    lines = new JButton("Lines");
    background = new JButton("Background");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());      

    //Draw Panel
    drawPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drawing Area"));


    //Drawing Speed
    JPanel drawSpeed = new JPanel();        
        drawSpeed.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        drawSpeed.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drawing Speed"));
        drawSpeed.add(draw);
        drawSpeed.add(pause);
        drawSpeed.add(clear);
        drawSpeed.add(speedSlider);
        drawSpeed.add(progress);

    //File Options
    JPanel fileOptions = new JPanel();
        fileOptions.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,350));
        fileOptions.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("File Options"));

        open.addActionListener(this);
        close.addActionListener(this);

        fileOptions.add(open);
        fileOptions.add(close);
        fileOptions.add(fileList);
        fileOptions.add(scrollPane);
    //Colour Options.
    JPanel colourOptions = new JPanel();        
        colourOptions.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        colourOptions.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Colour Options"));
        colourOptions.add(lines);
        colourOptions.add(background);

    //Control Panel
    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,200));

        controlPanel.add(drawSpeed);
        controlPanel.add(fileOptions);
        controlPanel.add(colourOptions);
        chooser = new JFileChooser(".");

    add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(drawPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == open){
                chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
                if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        drawing = new Drawing(chooser.getSelectedFile());
                        fileList.add(drawing);
                        listModel.addElement("test");

                }
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == close){

            }
        }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {


    }

public static void main(String[] args){

    DrawingDisplayer panel = new DrawingDisplayer();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("drawing");
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);      
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}



}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the problem you're having you need to understand that a component can only reside within a single container (it can only have a single parent).

If you try and add the component to another container, it is removed from the first before been added to the second.

So, in your code you do...

```
fileList = new JList(listModel);
//...
// Add fileList as the view for the scrollpane...
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileList);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));

//...
// Remove fileList from the scrollpane and add it to fileOptions...
fileOptions.add(fileList);
fileOptions.add(scrollPane);
```

...So, basically, you've started out well, but ended up removing the `fileList` from the `scrollPane` and adding it to the `fileOptions` instead, then added the (now empty) `scrollPane` to the `fileOptions` as well...

Remove `fileOptions.add(fileList);` and it should work as you expect it...

You might also want to take a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

You can control the size of the `JScrollPane` by using things like [`setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int)) and appropriate cell renderers ...

Comment: OMG YOU'RE A GENIUS!! I've been hitting my head against a wall trying to figure this out...THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Actually, I noticed that `"Test"` was been displayed, just not where it should be...which lead me to look into how the `JList` and `JScrollPane` where been used...and yes, I've done this myself :P

Comment: hey, when I try add a Drawing Object it doesn't show. Only "test" seems to display properly. Oh and I did change "fileList.add(drawing);" to "listModel.add(drawing);"

Comment: What is `Drawing`?  Does it have a `toString` implementation?  Have you tried using a custom list cell renderer?

Comment: Omg I'm so silly, I set my toString to return null as I wasn't finished with it, so it WAS being displayed but with no text. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

The default rendering of an object added to the ListModel is to simple display the `toString()` of the object.

If you are adding a custom object, then you need to provide a custom renderer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), especially the section on `Writing a Custom Cell Renderer` for more information on this concept.